# Launching a rails app in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, web-deployment, production-environment

Planning on launching your first rails app? I am as well, and any guides that one can provide on launching an initial rails application would be extremely useful!

With that being said, what are the best practices when taking an application from it's development stage, to production?

For example; I've read that running production server on WEBrick is bad practices, and that the vanilla MySQL (and Postgres for that matter) configuration sucks. SO it would be best not to open production without properly tuning them.

Any other thoughts, experiences or sources for best practices when launching a rails app in production would be great! Ideally I would like to avoid as many issues as possible ahead of time, so this is a pivotal moment.

Answer (score 1):

IF you planning on launching your first app using heroku please see the following detailed guide: [Heroku Guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3). Having said that before you launch your application to heroku, it is best practice to `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`. This precompiles your assets. Having done that refer to the supplied guide.